# How to analyze two-sided scale (too high-OK-too low)?

Tags: t-test, likert

just not to invent the wheel: what is the standard approach to compare two variables coded by two-sided scale where the best value at the center and two types of the worst outcomes on the ends (too high-just OK-too low)?

Two-step procedure comes to my mind: recode to one side to learn which variable is "better" and then split each variable by two to learn the direction of superiority.

Anything more elegant?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to determine.  It will help you to clearly formulate what you want to know.  To me, from the question, it sounds like you want to treat one value as essentially *good*, and the other two as essentially *bad*.  If so, recode the data this way.  There are various statistical tests you could use at that point, but the essential descriptive statistic is the proportion of *good* in each sample. ... As you say, then you could do a different analysis to determine if the *bad* has more to do with *too low* or *too high*.

Comment: Just to clarify, I assumed that scale has few points like this: -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5. This is like two Likert scale combined. -5 and +5 are bad and 0 is good. Obviously, standard tests like T-test will not work here as well as tests of proportion because it is scale, not a nominal choice.